# iPhone/iTouch information in a Cocoa App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

How would you retrieve the iPhone/iPod Touch information in a cocoa app, (not an app for the devices), ie such as what iTunes does to show the information of your connected device?

Thanx!

Comment: Stop. There's no such thing as an iTouch. Come back and ask again later.

Comment: Not going to get on to semantics or argument on that one, many people call it different things.

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to get much sympathy on a technical Q&A site if you take a "whatever it's called" attitude. It's important to be precise.

Answer (score 2):

You mean how many apps, how many podcasts, the titles and stuff? Sorry, i don't think you can do that.

Comment: Seconded. Apple has never released the specification for communicating with a device directly over USB.

Comment: I know it can be done, look at an application called f0recast, iPhone browser (which uses a dll to connect to it, but Manzana is for windows), so I do know it can be accomplished, and that's what's driving my mind crazy, but thank you!

Comment: Ah, interesting. They must have reverse engineered something. That is possible but - it is by it's very nature a hack. It could take ages and could all be a waste of time when apple change things around next week… fire up GDB!

Comment: will try that, I forget about GDB, that little bugger. (yes pun intended).  Just hope I can make sense of the assembly, was never good with assembler.

Comment: Maybe something like this would help http://modmyi.com/forums/windows-specific-modding-discussion/1955-iphonelist-iphone-file-explorer-open-source.html

Comment: Grant it this is for windows, but could possibly translate over to OSX! :)
Thanx! Will have a go at it!  I appreciate the search and find!